# "No network devices available" when wireless previously worked. (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, kernel

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop. The last time I used it (several weeks ago) the wireless was working fine. I turned it on today and no networks will show up, with the network menu saying "No network devices available."

I've disabled and enabled networking, and restarted the computer several times now. I've also tried pressing the key combination to turn the wireless adapter off and back on (FN+F2), but that didn't seem to do anything.

Most other posts I've seen while searching for solutions are cases of people having problems when they initially install the OS and not having drivers. It worked before for me so I know I have working drivers installed. I haven't messed with drivers or updated the system, or done anything with it at all since I last used it.

I've seen people on other posts request running `iwconfig` and `ifconfig` for more information, results of those below:

`iwconfig`:

```
no wireless extensions.
```

`ifconfig`:

```
Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
RX packets:161 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:161 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:11409 (11.4 KB)  TX bytes:11409 (11.4 KB)
```

Edit:
Requested output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0208]
```

Edit 2:
Requested output of `dpkg -l | grep linux-image`

```
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-32-generic        3.13.0-32.57  amd64  Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-34-generic        3.13.0-34.60  amd64  Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-59-generic        3.13.0-59.98  amd64  Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-32-generic  3.13.0-32.57  amd64  Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-34-generic  3.13.0-34.60  amd64  Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                  3.13.0.34.40  amd64  Generic Linux kernel image
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Added to original post.

Comment: Please also add output of `dpkg -l | grep linux-image`

Comment: Edit: Nevermind my original comment here if you saw it, adding to original post now.

Comment: Please post the whole output of the command to your question. It looks like you do not have the correct `linux-image-extra`. Can you connect to internet by wire?

Comment: Added it, was just a bit confused when I posted the other comment.

Comment: So that's what I suspected. See the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not have `linux-image-extra` for the running kernel 3.13.0-59. The kernel module `ath9k` is not installed. That is probably because the upgrade had been interrupted.

You need to connect to the internet by wire and run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If that does not install the `extras`, you can manually install them by

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-3.13.0-59-generic
```

but this means that some dependencies are not correct.

If you can't connect by wire, then boot with one of the previous kernels using grub menu. The wifi should work.

Then run the same commands.

Another option is to switch to 3.19 kernel by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

Comment: Don't have an ethernet port on this PC so I can't use a wired connection, but I ran the 3.13.0-34 kernel, wireless works fine on that. Ran the update and upgrade commands (took a bit, thus the late reply). Rebooted once those were finished and wireless is still showing "No network devices available" on the latest kernel.

Comment: That's weird. But you can run `sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-3.13.0-59-generic`. That must be a bug with dependencies..

Comment: Just to be clear, I should boot into 3.13.0-34 again and run that, correct?

Comment: Correct. Or the other command I added to the answer.

Comment: Tried the answer you posted in the comments here, rebooted, and wireless is working fine on that now.Thanks so much for your help with this!

Comment: @EliSilverhand Run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`. You have an outdated kernel.

Comment: Ran the dist-upgrade as well. Everything seems to still be working fine after that. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Although, this is not an answer-answer to this problem, but one of the quicker one-time solution. If you experiencing this issue, and you want wi-fi rather sooner then later, then reboot Ubuntu, select "`Advanced options for Ubuntu`" on startup, and when the list appears select `first next version of kernel` other then the very top once (which is the one you use when you normally boot to Ubuntu). 
Also, when saying "First next" by that I mean **skip** any options that has `recovery mode` label added.

The kernel might have been corrupted, so if you want a quick solution and need wi-fi immediately, switch to using some of the older versions of the kernel, and it should work (worked for me).