# No network devices found 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking

I booted up my Dell Studio Laptop today and had no wireless network connection.

`ifconfig -a` returns:

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet 6 addr:  ::1/128  Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets: 3184 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets: 3184 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:267904 (267.9 KB)  TX bytes:267904 (267.9kb)
```

Output of lspci -knn:

```
    00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub [8086:2a40] (rev 07)
            Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:02ea]
            Kernel driver in use: agpgart-intel
    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series ChipSet Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:2a42] (rev 07)
               Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:02ea] (rev 07)
    00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4 [8086:2937] (rev 03)
              Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:02ea]
              Kernel Driver in use: uhci_hcd
    00:1a.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5 [8086:2937] (rev 03)
              Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:02ea]
              Kernel Driver in use: uhci_hcd
    00:1a.2 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6 [8086:2937] (rev 03)
              Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:02ea]
              Kernel Driver in use: uhci_hcd
    00:1a.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 [8086:2937] (rev 03)
              Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:02ea]
              Kernel Driver in use: ehci_pci
    00:1b.0 Audio device [0403}: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD AUdio Controller [8086:293e] (rev 03)
    00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 1 [8086:2940] (rev 03)
              Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 2 [8086:2942] (rev 03)
              Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 3 [8086:2944] (rev 03)
              Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 4 [8086:2946] (rev 03)
              Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 5 [8086:2948] (rev 03)
              Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    00:1c.5 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) PCI Express Port 6 [8086:294a] (rev 03)
              Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1 [8086:2934] (rev 03)
              Subsystem: Dell Dvice [1028:02ea]
              Kernel driver in use: uhci_hd
    00:1d.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2 [8086:2935] (rev 03)
              Subsystem: Dell Dvice [1028:02ea]
              Kernel driver in use: uhci_hd
    00:1d.2 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3 [8086:2936] (rev 03)
              Subsystem: Dell Dvice [1028:02ea]
              Kernel driver in use: uhci_hd
    00:1d.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1 [8086:293a] (rev 03)
              Subsystem: Dell Dvice [1028:02ea]
              Kernel driver in use: ehci_pci
    00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobil PCI Bridge [8086:2448] (rev 93)

    00:1f.o ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation ICH9m-E Interface Controller [8086:2917] (rev 03)
              Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:02ea]
    00:1f.2 SATA Controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 82801IBM/IEM (ICH9m/ICH9m-E) 4 Port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [8086:2929] (rev 03)
                 Subsystem Dell Device [1028:02ea]
                 Kernel driver in use: ahci
    00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) SMBus Controller [8086:2930] (rev 03)
                 Subsystem Dell Device [1028:02ea]
    08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 [8086:4232]
            Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wifi Link 5100 AGN [8086:1321]
    14:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394) [0c00]: O2 Micro, Inc. 1394 OHCI Compliant Host Controller [1217:10f7] (rev 01)
                      Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:02ea]
    14:00.1 SD Host Controller [0805]:O2 Micro, Inc. Integrated MMC/SD Controller [1217:8120] (rev 01)
       Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:02ea]
    14:00.2 Mass Storage controller [0180]: O2 Micro, Inc. Integrated MS/MSPRO/xD Controller [1217:8130] (rev 01)
                  Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:02ea]
    20:00.0 Ethernet Controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
               Subsystem: Dell Dvice [1028:02ea]
```

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci -knn`

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No network devices available" when wireless previously worked. (14.04)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/678707/no-network-devices-available-when-wireless-previously-worked-14-04)

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Sorry for the delay posting the edit.

Comment: "Can anyone offer assistance?" is a meta-question (you're asking to ask). Since there are apparently *two* inoperational networking devices on your computer and you mention both I need to ask: what's your actual question? Bear in mind that Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions (e. g. about multiple unrelated devices), you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-)

Comment: P.S.: You can still have multiple questions open at the same time, e. g. one for your Ethernet adapter and another for your wireless network adapter. Just don't put both into the same post and be clear about which one each question is about! :-)

Comment: David - Thanks for the information.  I will make an edit to my original question to make it clear.

Comment: What does `rfkill list` tell you ?

Comment: Have you checked the duplicate question proposed by @wjandrea?