# network not working updating to kernel 5.8 ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, kernel, iwlwifi

After updating the kernel to `5.8.0-36-generic` and rebooting I noticed the network wasn't working.

Using the previous working kernel I've found that the problem was related to drivers not present because my interfaces were `UNCLAIMED` using `lshw -c network`.

I've found other posts suggesting to install the  `linux-generic-hwe` in my case  `linux-generic-hwe-20.04`.

After installing it the interfaces where recognized.

I can't quite get what happened, and probably don't quite know where to look for information about this, the previous kernel worked fine.
I don't understand if the driver was removed between kernel releases or something else..

The output of `sudo lshw -c network` with the network working is pasted here:

```
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Dual Band Wireless-AC 3168NGW [Stone Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 10
       serial: 60:f6:77:65:e5:69
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-36-generic firmware=29.1654887522.0 3168-29.ucode ip=192.168.1.9 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:128 memory:df100000-df101fff
```

So it looks is something related to `iwlwifi`.

Anybody can give any info regarding this, the update process finished with no errors, so I guess it's something else.

Comment: While booted into 5.8.0-36-generic, please run the terminal command: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl` Next, edit your question to show the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you asking about a wireless "network"?

Comment: Thank you so much for that tip about installing `linux-generic-hwe`. I was having the same issue and that solved it for me. And @chili555, running `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` without having that packaged installed returned an error (could not find module and missing symbol, I won't past it here to avoid polluting the comments).

Comment: @chili555 I'm sorry, after installing the hwe kernel the problem went away, so I can't try that.

Comment: @Pilot6 I used a wireless adapter to connect, but the wired interface was down too. From what i remember the wired one was down too before updating the kernel.

Answer (score 8):

Also lost network connection after updating from kernel 5.4.0 to kernel 5.8.0-41.

Looking at the output of

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-
```

I figured out that in my case the previous kernels had `linux-modules-extra-` packages installed, but `linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-41-generic` was missing. After booting a 5.4.0 kernel (with working network connection) I could fix the problem by

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-41-generic
```

Comment: Exactly the same here, any idea how this came about?

Comment: It worked for me! Thx a lot!!

Comment: @ozone one possibility is that the wrong architecture was selected/ detected? I have been researching it a bit, and it seems like this module is only included in the x64 variant. All of the other packages (i.e. the headers, image, etc. come packed for x86 & x64.) This is just a guess. I'm still trying to figure it out myself. Anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: My old kernel does not have extras installed either.

Comment: thank you! this solved my network issue after updating my kernel.

Answer (score 5):

I was also facing a similar problem with the wireless network and the touchpad not working after upgrading to 5.8 kernel.

I found this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678707/no-network-devices-available-when-wireless-previously-worked-14-04).

After running

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-
```

I found that the modules for `linux-modules-5.8.0-38-generic` wasn't installed but the previous kernel's modules were.

So if you can connect to a wired network, doing

```
sudo apt-get install linux-modules-5.8.0-38-generic linux-headers-5.8.0-38-generic
```

should install them. That seemed to work for me.

If you are like me, who cant connect to wired network, try switching the kernel in the grub ' Advanced options for Ubuntu ' to a previous working version of the kernel, and try installing the above.

Comment: I guess installing the hwe version of the kernel installed the modules too? I had to switch kernel to the previous version in grub to update.

Comment: Yeah must have been. For the modules, i also had to install the headers, but not all the headers were retreived for some reason.

Comment: I think you may have forgot the word "extras". The 'extras' package is the hardware enablement (hwe) package. Without thes packages, I doubt the system would boot. This is almost the entire kernel.

Comment: I think extras was already installed. I was able to boot to GUI. I just wasnt getting Wifi. Those must have been part of different packages.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when I updated to 5.8.0-63 kernel. My wifi, sound and graphics were messed up.

Following the answers by Jörg and Harish above, I booted into an older kernel with working internet from the Ubuntu advanced options in the boot menu and ran the following command

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-
```

I installed the 2 packages: headers and extra, that were missing for the newest kernel.

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-63-generic linux-headers-5.8.0-63-generic
```

After reboot, everything works perfectly again.

Answer (score 1):

I installed all the packages below solved my network and brightness issue:
Replace version `5.13.0-25` to `your_version`.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-5.13.0-25-generic linux-headers-5.13.0-25-generic linux-modules-5.13.0-25-generic linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-25-generic linux-hwe-5.13-headers-5.13.0-25
```