# 20.04.1 Another kernel 5.8 update victim. Lost all network devices!

Tags: 20.04, kernel, updates

So after accepting a regular update my system rebooted to no network devices. Wifi or ethernet.

Uname indicated a new kernel had been installed. 5.8.0.38

My devices are :

Qualcomm Atheros AR8151 V2.0 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1083] (rev c0)

Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0030] (rev c1)

After looking at these similar issues:

[network not working updating to kernel 5.8 ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1307447/network-not-working-updating-to-kernel-5-8-ubuntu-20-04)

[bcmwl-kernel-source broken on kernel: 5.8.0-34-generic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305699/bcmwl-kernel-source-broken-on-kernel-5-8-0-34-generic)

I installed the 5.8.0.36 modules and headers but still no network!

If a grub boot to the previous kernel everything works!

What should I look at next?

Comment: Maybe have a look here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu
To see if your issue is already reported.

Comment: i tried sudo modprobe atl1c and sudo modprob3e ath9k but receive fatal error Module xxx not found in /lib/modules/5.8.0-38-generic.  Looking in that directory all the files for those devices that are in the 5.4.0-62-generic directory structure are present.  So don't know whats wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and it was solved by also installing linux-modules-extra package (i.e. linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-34-generic)

Comment: How did you do that without network adapters?